# How to scale multi-core and parallel insert into using Oracle Database and Java 8?

Tags: jdbc, parallel-processing

I need to read data from DBF files and insert them to Oracle Enterprise 12g/13c environments to do join and extract reports from that. 
Everything is working properly but due to thousand of files and their sizes are between 0.5 to 1TB the execution has been spent hours to be finished.

The average speed is 7.000 records per second.

I am using RecursiveTask to open many connections to database to execute the inserts in parallel. Oracle can use parallel in many situations but not in this case. 
I am using auto commit OFF and the table has no index.

In addition, I am using parallelStream before execute the insert in batch, as following:

```
listInsert.parallelStream().forEach(line -> {
    try {
        statementDB.addBatch(line);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(line + "- ERRORCODE = " + e.getErrorCode() + " - " + e.getMessage());
    }
});
statementDB.executeBatch();
statementDB.getConnection().commit();
```

The problem is!
I need to be faster to import all data!

Any help to improve the performance for INSERT INTO or any other solution. I am thinking to use Hive on Hadoop

Comment: Let me add that the data are not readable as a CSV. I need to remove accent, treat problems related with commas, semicolon, apostrophe, wrong information and the structure of this files are different partially. So it is impossible to use SQL Loader.

Comment: I don’t think that doing `addBatch` in parallel will gain you much. To my experience, you have to tune the batch size. Of course, doing every line in an individual statement would be bad, but depending on the DB, too large batches may also affect the performance negatively. For some DBs, even having too much uncommitted data turns out to be inefficient, so if no atomic transaction is needed, committing in-between (not too often) may help. Alternatively, try inserting via a mutable `ResultSet` instead. That may be much better than a batch statement.

Comment: You can actually do pretty complicated preprocessing with SQLLoader. That would be the fastest tool for this. Could you give an example row of data?

Comment: Hi @Holger I have monitored the insert execution. I saw that there is a gap of execution inside Oracle Session when we are using  .executeUpdate() with "insert into table name". It is less efficient compared to .addBatch() and executeBatch(). There is no gap with .addBatch().

Comment: Regarding the size of batches I agree with you that depending on DB this can be different number. In my approach this number change depending on the length of DBF file.

Comment: Hi @MickMnemonic You are right about SQLLoader to be the best tool when we are talking about performance to insert data. We've tried with it and the different table's structure were the big problem. In addition, I did not know how to remove the accent of portuguese words. Any solution?

Comment: Maybe you could share details about the table structures and how they are causing problems? Regarding character conversions, it's possible to call PL/SQL functions on the data prior to import, e.g. `REPLACE(...)`

Comment: Hi @MickMnemonic I am using Oracle DB at company but I can share the DDL for MySQL. Sorry for to long structure. I have to add all possible columns.
CREATE TABLE `siasusab` (
  `AP_MVM` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CONDIC` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_GESTAO` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CODUNI` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_AUTORIZ` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CMP` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_PRIPAL` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_VL_AP` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_UFMUN` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: `AP_TPUPS` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_TIPPRE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_MN_IND` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CNPJCPF` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CNPJMNT` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CNSPCN` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_COIDADE` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_NUIDADE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_SEXO` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_RACACOR` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: `AP_MUNPCN` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_UFNACIO` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CEPPCN` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_UFDIF` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_MNDIF` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_DTINIC` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_DTFIM` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_TPATEN` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_TPAPAC` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_MOTSAI` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: `AP_OBITO` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_ENCERR` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_PERMAN` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_ALTA` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_TRANSF` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_DTOCOR` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CODEMI` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CATEND` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_APACANT` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_UNISOL` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_DTSOLIC` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_DTAUT` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CIDCAS` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CIDPRI` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_CIDSEC` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: `AP_ETNIA` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_IMC` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_PROCAIH` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_DTCIRUR` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_NUMAIH` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_PRCAIH2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_PRCAIH3` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_NUMAIH2` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_DTCIRG2` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_MESACOM` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_ANOACOM` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: `AB_PONTBAR` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AB_TABBARR` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AP_NATJUR` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL
)

Comment: Any column need to be checked if there is this curl braces, parentheses, apostrophe, comma, semi-comma, quotation marks and be replaced by space

Comment: Any accent need to be replaced by the same letter without accent

Comment: I really don't know to treat theses rules using SQLLoader

Comment: So, what is the problem with the table structure?

Comment: Hi @MickMnemonic  Please, let me know if is possible to load different DBF files  structures using SQLLoader into this table